# Question on RDF and how thisweknow.org works

Tags: rdf, sparql

I was reading through this question

[What's a RDF triple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273218/what-is-an-rdf-triple)

and the excellent answers to it.

Roger Federer | won | wimbledon

I understand that the above sentence is a triplet.  But if the sentence is

Roger Federer won wimbledon in 2009,

how do we represent it as a RDF triplet?

This site thisweknow.org allows users to query the data.gov data starting with a town/city. Can someone give an example of how the data would look like, in their db? Its quite impressive, but I *have* to start with a town/city, can't do it at the state level (as far as I could see).  I assume they would be allowing users to query data at county/state/national level soon, can it be done without significant changes to the data structure they have now?  If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Roger Federer | won | tournamentX
tournamentX | year |2009
tournamentX | site | Wimbledon
```

Or, maybe more clearly:

```
tournamentX | winner | Roger Federer
tournamentX | year |2009
tournamentX | site | Wimbledon
```

The main trick to data-modeling in RDF, or any other node/arc-based language, is understanding where you need intermediate objects that represent combinations of things. Here you need a "tournament" node that has a year, a site and a winner. "tournamentX" is an arbitrary ID for it.